# convert the xml to json array using php

Tags: php, xml, laravel, soap, php-5.3

I am using soap api this is the response data i want from it. when i use the php function

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http">
<s:Body>
    <ValidateESSLoginUsingEmpIDResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <ValidateESSLoginUsingEmpIDResult xmlns:a="" xmlns:i="">
            <a:IsSuccessful>true</a:IsSuccessful>
            <a:Message>Login Successful</a:Message>
        </ValidateESSLoginUsingEmpIDResult>
    </ValidateESSLoginUsingEmpIDResponse>
</s:Body>
```

it returns me the data array

```
 $result=str_replace('s:', '', $result);
 $result=str_replace('a:', '', $result);
 $xml=simplexml_load_string($result);
 print_r($xml);
```

but i don't want to replace (S:,a:). is there any other way to get that data

Comment: use `DOMDocument`, `DOMXPath` and `registerNamespace`

Comment: where should i use it can you explain please

Comment: the above snippet of xml seems to be incomplete - easier with the actual code

Comment: yes i know i am getting this response from soap API

Comment: i have solution which i have mention  in the question but i want is there any other way

Comment: The response `s:Envelope xmlns:s="http"` does not seem correct... have you edited it?

Comment: Use your SOAP client. there is no need to meddle with the transfer layer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I released a package to convert xml to an array. You can find it here: https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array

You can try it out on your xml and see what happens, but it appears the xml you provided is not valid, so I recommend trying it with the actual soap response.